# Am I using the right linear mixed model design for my data?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, python, linear-model, statsmodels

I want to move from using repeat measure ANOVAs to linear mixed models (LMM). However, where I have good intuitions about ANOVAs, LMMs are new to me. I'm using python's StatsModels as my package. Here's the form of my data:

```
participant_ID  Condition_1 Condition_2 dependent_var
1               1           1           0.71
1               2           1           0.43
2               1           1           0.77
2               2           1           0.37
3               1           1           0.58
3               2           1           0.69
4               2           1           0.72
4               1           1           0.12
26              2           2           0.91
26              1           2           0.53
27              1           2           0.29
27              2           2           0.39
28              2           2           0.75
28              1           2           0.51
29              1           2           0.42
29              2           2           0.31
```

As you can seen, this is a classic repeat-measures ANOVA design, with fixed effects nested in participants. What I wish to do is establish (1) the independent effects of Condition_1 and Condition_2, and (2) the effect of their interaction, all on dependent_var. My statsmodels code is as follows:

```
md = smf.mixedlm("dependent_var ~ C(Condition_1)+C(Condition_2) + C(Condition_1):C(Condition_2)", toy_data, groups=toy_data["participant_ID]).fit()
```

This outputs the following summary.

[image: Summary Table]

Allowing that this data is contrived, and p values are meaningless, etc, etc, am I correct to read this as saying that neither variable is significant as a main effect, and neither is their interaction?

I appreciate that LMMs aren't ANOVAs and I should avoid translating them into ANOVAs, but my actual data was arranged for an ANOVA design, and I wish to be confident in my interpretation.

Comment: You mention that "fixed effects are nested in participants", but in the data excerpt, it each subject appears to be uniquely assigned to one of the two values of Condition_2, suggesting that this factor is between-group. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, yes, Condition_2 is between-group. I probably used the wrong terminology in describing it as nested.

Comment: Generally speaking, repeated-measures ANOVAs are simply a specific type of linear mixed model (LMM). In other words, repeated-measured ANOVAs are a subset of linear mixed models, so it doesn't really make sense to say you want to move from one to the other (unless you mean you want your model to be more general).  But there are some important differences in the terminology.  See here for example:  https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/six-differences-between-repeated-measures-anova-and-linear-mixed-models/

Comment: I accept that they're versions of the same thing in the statistical sense; when I say 'move' I mean simply that LMMs are the model I select, largely for reasons of their ability to better deal with missing data than ANOVAs. My question centres on whether the specific model I implement in my code is appropriate to the structure of my data.

Comment: @Lodore66 They aren't two versions of some overarching model, a repeated measures ANOVA *is* a (type of) linear mixed model, so there is no reason why it would have different proporties like the ability to deal with missingness. Second, if there is indeed an interaction effect, you cannot then estimate the independent/main effects of the variables in the interaction as this violates the principle of marginality.

Comment: @Frans Rodenburg: I'm certainly far from an expert in this area, which is why I'm posting. However, my understanding is that an ANOVA design requires balanced samples, where any participant who isn't measured for all relevant conditions must be deleted from the sample? Thanks for the advice on the principle of marginality. So how should I test for the independent/main effects if I detect an interaction first? Thanks.

Comment: How you deal with missing data is a whole different problem, whether your regression is an ANOVA or not. What you describe is called list-wise deletion and is only valid under strict assumptions (MCAR). Can you edit your question to clarify what exactly is the culprit of your modeling problem?

Comment: @FransRodenburg *"Repeated measures ANOVA is a (type of) linear mixed model, so there is no reason why it would have different proporties like the ability to deal with missingness"*: I'm very surprised by this claim, the difference in how missing data is handled is mentioned in pretty much anything I have read on rmANOVA and LMM. Even in practice, R code for rmANOVA won't run without list-wise deletion, which can be extremely problematic for some designs. I'm not a statistician, but for all practical purposes of a user, it is confusing to read that rmANOVA is just a linear mixed model.

Comment: ANOVA is just an interpretation of a linear model with only categorical variables by partitioning variance. How the R function `aov` handles missing values has nothing to do with that, and any problems that missingness would cause in ANOVA, would cause the same theoretical problems for a linear model with categorical variables.

Comment: @FransRodenburg: My original question centred on whether I was using the right model for my data. You comments suggest that I should first test for an interaction; if that isn't significant, I should only then test the two variables independently. If so, question answered, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with an additive "variance components" model, I think the Python/Statsmodels code you want is like this:

```
# df is your "toy data"
df["groups"] = 0                                                                                           

fml = "dependent_var ~ 1"                                                                                  
vcf = {"participant": "0 + C(participant_ID)", 
       "cond1": "0 + C(Condition_1)",                              
       "cond2": "0 + C(Condition_2)"}                                                                      
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula(
           fml, vc_formula=vcf, 
           groups="groups", data=df)                             
result = model.fit(method='powell')
```

Since your Condition_1 and Condition_2 are crossed, you need to put everyone in a single group and use the variance components argument to specify all the random effects.

I get the results below:

```
           Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
===========================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: dependent_var
No. Observations: 16      Method:             REML         
No. Groups:       1       Scale:              0.0459       
Min. group size:  16      Likelihood:         0.4363       
Max. group size:  16      Converged:          Yes          
Mean group size:  16.0                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------
                   Coef. Std.Err.   z   P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------
Intercept          0.531    0.054 9.917 0.000  0.426  0.636
cond1 Var          0.000    0.133                          
cond2 Var          0.000                                   
participant Var    0.000    0.089                          
===========================================================
```

For comparison, the R results are below, they are the same.

```
> lmer(dependent_var ~ (1|participant_ID) + (1|Condition_1) + (1|Condition_2), data=df)
singular fit
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: dependent_var ~ (1 | participant_ID) + (1 | Condition_1) + (1 |  
    Condition_2)
   Data: df
REML criterion at convergence: -0.8726
Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Std.Dev.
 participant_ID (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Condition_1    (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Condition_2    (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Residual                   0.2143  
Number of obs: 16, groups:  participant_ID, 8; Condition_1, 2; Condition_2, 2
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
     0.5312  
convergence code 0; 1 optimizer warnings; 0 lme4 warnings
```

Both packages struggle with the optimization since your variance parameters are on the boundary.  I had to use the non-default "powell" option in Statsmodels to get a converged result.

I'm not sure if you care about this data set, or if you just are using this as an example.  But the interpretation here would be that there is no evidence for additive effects of participant, Condition_1, or Condition_2 in relation to your dependent variable, at least in an additive sense.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! Don't know why I only saw it now; SE never notified me of it. But great, perfect answer.